# How to handle unknown dependencies in Makefile that are dynamically detected?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

Let's say my Makefile is building a website. I write a `index.html` containing assets, like this:

```
<html>
  <body><img src="asset/foo.img"/></body>
</html>
```

Now I want to write a rule to create a ZIP archive that contains the HTML as well as its assets.

I write a script to parse out the `src=` attributes, but what do I do with it?
If I put that in a recipe, but at that point the Makefile rules can't be changed.
If I put it in a `$(shell ...)` command, then it will have to run every time the Makefile is parsed, even if the user is doing a `clean` or something.

What is the proper way to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think I just figured it out myself. The solution is a sub-call to `$(MAKE)`—in fact, its primary difference compared to `include` seems to be the fact that it occurs at recipe execution time rather than at parse time.

Comment: This may interest you: [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).At the end, there is a brief mention of "Dependencies For Non-C Files", which seems to apply to your situation. In the end, your case is not much different from the 'common' case where `.o` files are built from `.c` files that include `.h` files.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek: Thanks but the language is not the issue. Notice that in that scenario the `.h` files are not used during the same build after the `.c` is compiled, so merely noting its presence in a `.d` file is enough. In this scenario I need to process the dependency for the same build, so I effectively need to process a rule that mentions every dependency as a target in the *same* invocation of Make.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
assets := $(shell ./myscript index.html)

myzip.zip: index.html $(assets)
    zip $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to miss your problem. Isn't it that a dependency tree of your situation looks like this:

```
my_page.html   image1.bmp    image2.bmp
  |    |           |            |
  1    2           2            2
  |    |           |            |
  |     \          |           /
  |      \         |          /
  |       \        |         /
  |        \       |        /
  |         \      |       /
  |          \     |      /
depend.dep    archive.zip
```

where "1" is the rule which scans `my_page.html` for all assets and writes them back to `depend.dep` (or the makefile itself, that doesn't change the solution) and "2" is updating the zip file with changed member files? As make is trying to re-make `depend.dep` (or `makefile` itself) prior to any other rule, you always have an up-to-date dependency list when starting a make-run which will do exactly as you command: add/update members to `archive.zip` if they are newer. I say it again: re-parsing `my_page.html` if it has changed relative to the dependencies is step *zero* in a make-run, if there exists a dependency towards a file which is `include`d or `makefile` itself.

Comment: Did you give this solution a second thought?