# Is make --dry-run supposed to generate dependency files?

Tags: makefile

I see a dilemma with Makefiles:

- If I generate dependencies (`*.d`) during a dry-run, then it's no longer a dry run... and this may involve doing a lot of processing for all the files.
- If I don't generate dependencies, then `make -n` won't actually display what is going to happen.

What is the accepted resolution to this problem?

Comment: How do you use dry-run in your development cycle? One recent example is Android Studio gradle plugin for C++. It does good job in the simple scenarios, but becomes extremely tricky as soon as the makefile (Android.mk) goes off the beaten path.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I don't use it regularly for development, it's mostly to help me debug the Makefile dependencies themselves.

Comment: IMHO, for debugging, dry-run is too different from the real thing. You can turn on verbose output, and you also need the tools to undo your make, fix something in the makefile, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a [more advanced method](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) of auto-dependency generation, that won't have this problem.

Comment: Ack, I see why you said this. I completely neglected to mention this (my bad) but the dependencies in my case are needed in the *same* run, not in the next run. See here, where I was struggling with another aspect of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53732165/541686

Comment: What you describe there, is not dependencies, but rather the list of all involved assets. Like, if my C project has a new C source added: it's not covered unless I add the project file itself as a prerequisite that requires full rebuild

Comment: @AlexCohn: Yeah I'm not sure what wording to use for it, but that's the problem I'm encountering.

Comment: The `.d` files are traditionally used with auto-generated dependency tracking files.  It sounds like what you have are auto-generated source files.  The answer to your question depends on what you want to do.  Do _you_ want `make -n` to generate these source files?  Or not?